# Ansible 2.8: Access a list object element

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

In Ansible 2.8, I need to deploy and config Bind 9 DNS on Ubuntu Server VMs. I have a:

1. DNS Ansible role to do the installation and config,
2. a list of variables per domain zone (as DNS record type, domain name, dns entry,...). Until here, it works, the issues appear when I try to make it accept the next requirement:
3. potentially, several domain zones to configure in the same call, threfore, I send to it a list with groups of variables (mentioned in 2).

For now, in the shell, I call it with 1 element list, using:

```
--extra-vars "{"dns_entry_conf": 
     [domain=example.gal ip=192.168.167.166 
     nameserver1=example.gal nameserver1_ip=192.168.167.164 
     dns_record1_type=A ...]}"
```

Inside the role, the `roles/dns/tasks/configure.yml` file receives the right value, but the file that follows, doesn't: it says "list object has no attribute", and I started debugging in the configure.yml file,  but I am not sure how to access the list object item:

```
---
- debug:
    msg: "{{dns_entry_conf}}"
- debug:
        msg: "{{dns_entry_conf | json_query(\"domain\") }}"
```

The first line prints what it should, but the 2nd does not... How I can access the value

```
ASK [dns : debug] **********************************************************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/roles/dns/tasks/configure.yml:2
ok: [ubuntuServer16_test] => {
    "msg": [
        "domain=example.gal ip=192.168.167.166 nameserver1=example.gal nameserver1_ip=192.168.167.164 
        dns_record1_type=A ...
    ]
}

TASK [dns : debug] **********************************************************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/roles/dns/tasks/configure.yml:4
ok: [ubuntuServer16_test] => {
    "msg": ""
}
```

In debug, tried with the msg's: `"{{ dns_entry_conf.domain }}"`, `"{{ dns_entry_conf.0 }}"`, `"{{dns_entry_conf | json_query(\"domain\") }}"`, `"{{ dns_entry_conf.list | json_query('[*].domain') }}"`, and others that were sintactically wrong, but it never outputs what I want.

Probably there are more wrong things (I am no Ansible expert), but, for now, just trying to debug and fix one by one, so, **I just want to know how I can access the "dns_entry_conf.domain" item, please**... some idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option1:**
with extra-vars as below:

```
 --extra-vars '{"dns_entry_conf":{"domain":example,"ip":1.2.3.4}}'
```

Playbook:

```
  - debug:
     msg: "{{dns_entry_conf.domain}}"
```

Output:

> ok: [localhost] => {
>       "msg": "example"
>   }

**Option2**:
with extra vars as below:

```
--extra-vars '{"dns_entry_conf":["domain":example,"ip":1.2.3.4]}'
```

In Playbook tey as below:

```
  - debug:
     msg: "{{dns_entry_conf[0].domain}}"
```

Output:

> ok: [localhost] => {
>       "msg": "example"
>   }

**Option 3:**
Pass the variables in the playbook.

```
  vars:
   dns_entry_conf:
    domain: example
    ip: 1.2.34.4
  tasks:
  - debug:
     msg: "{{dns_entry_conf.domain}}"
```

Output:

> ok: [localhost] => {
>       "msg": "example"
>   }

Comment: Option 1 worked, thank you. I haven't tested yet the 2nd